# Node.js: Change view based on server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I want to change the rendered webpage, with regards to a server response.

More detailed, i have an error page that is generic, but if the Node server does not find a user, i want to pass that data to the view, and i want the error message to change to "user not found".

This is the code on the server side:

```
getUserProfile(username).then(user=>{
      // bla bla
    }).catch(err => {
       if (err.code == 'NONEXISTANT_USER') {
           var wrongUser = 'true';  
           res.render('error.ejs', {overwrite:wrongUser});
        }
        else {
            res.render('error.ejs');
        }
        wrongUser = 'false';
    });
```

And this is the code on the ejs template:

```
<script>
      var checking_for_user = <%- JSON.stringify(overwrite) %> ;
      if (checking_for_user) {
        document.querySelector('.msg .text-center').innerHTML='User does not exist! Please go back to the <a href="/index">Index Page</a>';
      }
    </script>
```

And below that, somewhere on the ejs file:

```
<div class="msg">
                <h1 class= "text-center">There was an error. Please go back to the <a href="/index">Index Page</a> </h1>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work as the message never changes.
I have experimented with tweaking many variables but i just don't get it.

Comment: true and false shouldnt be strings. Or did you mean to do that?

Comment: Yeah i said what's the big deal...

Comment: Tried it with them being boolean, still the same.

Comment: your want to always pass `overwrite` regardless (so true/false as a boolean, or expect it as a string `if(checking_for_user == 'true')`) or do some checking in the ejs that its defined else your going to get `var checking_for_user =  ;` rendered when its not set, which will break everything.

Comment: You mean i should pass  res.render('error.ejs', {overwrite:0}); in the other case?

Comment: yeah as its using the same view, you could simplify the nodejs side with just one line `res.render('error.ejs', {overwrite: err.code == 'NONEXISTANT_USER'});`, dont need the if statement, each to own ;p

Comment: Thanksbut it still didn't work... I don't get why...

Comment: are you confident that `(err.code == 'NONEXISTANT_USER')` is equal and you are entering this if statement? PS always test equality with `===`